# $\lambda$-invariants in cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extensions

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves, iwasawa-theory

The idea that Selmer groups and class groups are related is not new. More recently, we understand that the growth patterns of fine Selmer groups are very similar to that of class groups in cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions of number fields. There are results where the classical $\mu$-invariant has been compared with the $\mu$-invariant of the (fine) Selmer group (eg Coates-Sujatha 2005, Kestutis Cesnavcius 2015).

Has there been any work done in comparing the $\lambda$-invariants? My understanding is that Greenberg conjectured that for totally real fields $\lambda=0$. This I think is still an open problem. Are there similar conjectures for $\lambda$-invariants for (fine) Selmer groups?

Hachimori-Matsuno had worked out an analogue of Kida's formula for Selmer groups, and therefore can give an explicit formula for $\lambda(F_{cyc}/F)$ in terms of $\lambda(K_{cyc}/K)$ where $F/K$ is a $p$-power extension. They showed that in some cases, the growth $\lambda$-invariant of Selmer groups and the class group have a similar pattern. Are there any other such results?

Comment: This paper might be relevant: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.13247.pdf